# Adding line breaks after times in parentheses

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-re

I'm trying to clean up some data from web scraping.

This is an example of the information I'm working with:

```
Best Time
Adam Jones (w/ help) (6:34)Best Time
Kenny Gobbin (a) (2:38)Personal Best
Matt Herrera (12:44)No-record
Nick Elizabeth (19:04)
```

And this is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Best Time
Adam Jones (w/ help) (6:34)

Best Time
Kenny Gobbin (2:38)

Personal Best
Matt Herrera (12:44)

No-record
Nick Elizabeth (19:04)
```

I want to add two new lines after each right parentheses, but as the times are all different, I don't know how I can search and replace it. Also, numbers may sometimes occur outside of the times.

The closest I've come is by searching for numbers inside the parentheses with a colon to separate them, but I don't know how to replace that with the same information.

```py
re.sub(r"\([0-9]+:[0-9]+\)", "\n\n", result)
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it your way with a minimal change. You only have to know about grouping and add `\g<0>` right befor `\n\n`. You can read about it in the offical documentation in the section about [search-and-replace](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace).

```
re.sub(r"\([0-9]+:[0-9]+\)", "\g<0>\n\n", result)
```

Here I used group 0 (the match in `()`) to insert it again. Each set of `()` is a group, counted from the left to the right started with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the place where you need to insert two newlines comes between an end parenthesis and an alphabetic character. So, you can use:

```py
re.sub(r"\)([A-Za-z])", r")\n\n\1", data)
```

For example:

```py
import re
data = """Best Time
Adam Jones (w/ help) (6:34)Best Time
Kenny Gobbin (a) (2:38)Personal Best
Matt Herrera (12:44)No-record
Nick Elizabeth (19:04)"""

result = re.sub(r"\)([A-Za-z])", r")\n\n\1", data)
print(result)
```

outputs:

```
Best Time
Adam Jones (w/ help) (6:34)

Best Time
Kenny Gobbin (a) (2:38)

Personal Best
Matt Herrera (12:44)

No-record
Nick Elizabeth (19:04)
```

---

Here's an explanation for how it works:

For the expression we're trying to match, we have `r"\)([A-Za-z])"`:

- `\)` matches a literal end parenthesis.
- `[A-Za-z]` matches a single alphabetic character.
- Enclosing `[A-Za-z]` in parentheses makes it a capture group that we refer to later.

For the replacement expression, we have `r")\n\n\1"`:

- `)\n\n` adds an end parenthesis plus two new lines.
- `\1` refers to the capture group from earlier. Intuitively, we capture the alphabetic character immediately after the end parenthesis, and then add that same character back into the replacement expression.

Comment: No problem! Have a great day! :)